# Three.js transparent background with a masked scene

Tags: three.js, rendering, shader, masking, post-processing

I'm new to coding and everyday I learn something new. I want to have a masked scene with other 3D objects, that are from other scenes, to be behind and around it. At this moment I'm stuck with a masked scene.  Right now I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/at4rumn6/3/) working. As u can see the background is grey and other 3D objects, that are from other scenes and behind the masked scene, can't be seen because of it.

How can I make the backround from masked scene to be transparent with other 3D objects from other scenes?

I think it has something to do with the `fragmentShader`, because I can change the background color by changing this line `"vec4 background = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);",.`

Thanks in advance for all the help!

**Update**

I understand that the background is transparent on [this previous link](http://jsfiddle.net/at4rumn6/3/), but I fail to create a new scene with new 3D objects that is visible and is outside the masked scene. Just helping me make a new scene on that previous link would help me out with my problem.

Comment: if i understood well it yet is transparent, the grey background comes from the css `background-color` property of `body`

Comment: In my code I have no `background-color` in css. The color of the background is defined by `vec4 background = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0)` and it's not transparent. I have multiple scenes with other 3D objects and they all can't be seen because of the color defined by `vec4 background = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0)`.

Comment: i don't understand your example then. Do you mean you add an other scene, or another renderer behind the one in the fiddle ? Here the renderer's background is transparent (`renderer.setClearColor(0x000000,0);`) and the grey comes from the css.

Comment: Doesn't work with my other scenes. I'll try to recreate the problem.

Comment: ok. if you complete the fiddle with one of your other scenes it could help

Comment: Right now I'm having a problem creating a new scene that is outside the masked scene. I can see that on jsfiddle.net/at4rumn6/3 the background is transperant, but how can I create a new scene that is outside the masked scene? That would help me out, because i fail to create a new scene outside the masked scene.

Comment: I recreated my problem on jsfiddle.net/at4rumn6/27. You can see that I added a new scene with a blue box. But the blue box is hidden behind the masked scene. The masked scene layer got `vec4 background = vec4(1.0,0.1,0.1,0.1);` and still I can't see my blue box from the new scene. 
I added a new composer and VignetteShader to render the new scene. For some reason I have to add VignetteShader to the new composer. I can only see my new scene when the masked scene is not rendered. `Renderer.autoClearColor = false;` makes masked scene glitched and so I dont know how to render all at once.

Comment: i can't get it right, maybe someone better skilled can help. I can jut advise to go step-by-step (and indent your code^^) : there are 2 composers, the copypass is not used, the vignette is not rendered... have a better look at the examples you took the code from and it will work. What i've done for now is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Atrahasis/at4rumn6/38/), switch `scenePass` and `maskPass` in the composer's `addPass` instructions and you will see one or the other.

Comment: The best result I could get is to get the masked scene behind the new scene, but then the masked scene couldn't be seen fully because of the objects on the new scene infront. I want the masked scene to be infront. I found a alternative way to use the 3D object as a mask, but I dont know how to place the image on the position I want. I want the image to behave like a sprite on the fixed position and window resize like in a average scene render. Anyway thank you for all the effort.